# SCons dependency on files generated at compile-time

Tags: dependencies, code-generation, scons

I'm trying to set up SCons to follow dependencies on files that are generated automatically during the build, and work correctly with a multi-threaded build.

The project I'm building is a CIM provider, consisting of MOF files defining the data structures, autogenerated source and header files that come from the MOF files, and handwritten source and header files that reference the autogenerated files.  In order for the build to succeed, the autogeneration step must run to completion before any of the handwritten files are compiled, otherwise the headers the handwritten files rely on will not exist yet and it will fail.  The .cpp files that are created by the autogeneration step must also be added to the source list and compiled in the final build.

When running a single threaded build, everything works fine, because the autogeneration step is always complete before the compilation step, so the generated headers are in place.  However, when running the build multi-threaded, it tries to compile the handwritten files before the autogeneration step has finished, and the build fails.  I have specified an explicit dependency but SCons is not following it.

Here is the relevant portion of my SConscript file, I removed individual filenames from cim_targets[] because the list is VERY long, but to summarize, cim_targets[] is the list of target output files for the autogeneration step, provider_sources[] is the returned list of sources after the autogen step completes, sources[] is the list of handwritten source files, GenProvider() is a Command builder defined externally that executes the autogeneration step, and SharedLibrary() is an externally defined builder that does what it sounds like, uses the SCons library builder with a few extensions

```
# Define directory paths for the CIM schema
cim_dir = 'cim-schema-2.26.0'

var_smis_dir   = Dir('.').abspath # src/lib/XXX in variant

cim_sources = [
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, '*qualifiers*.mof')),
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, 'Core')     + '/CIM_*.mof'),
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, 'Device')   + '/CIM_*.mof'),
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, 'Event')    + '/CIM_*.mof'),
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, 'XXXXXX')   + '/XXX_*.mof'),
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, 'Interop')  + '/CIM_*.mof'),
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, 'Physical') + '/CIM_*.mof'),
    Glob(os.path.join(cim_dir, 'System')   + '/CIM_*.mof'),
]

cim_sources_flat = []
for cim in cim_sources:
    for src in cim:
        cim_sources_flat.append(src)

cim_targets = [
    ......
]

sources = [
    'driver.cpp',
    'device.cpp',
    'cim_static_data.cpp',
    'module.cpp',
    'diag_log.cpp',
    'profile_element.cpp',
]

staticlibs = [
    ......
    ]


dynamiclibs = [
    .....
    ]

var_cim_sources = this_env.Install(var_smis_dir, cim_sources_flat)

cim_mof = 'cimv226.mof'

cim_linux_mof = os.path.join(cim_dir, 'cimv226-gen-flat.mof')

var_cim_sources.extend(this_env.Command(cim_mof, cim_linux_mof, Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE')))

# first generate the provider infrastructure using cimple
provider_sources = this_env.GenProvider(cim_targets, var_cim_sources, name, var_smis_dir)

# make sure these files don't build until AFTER the provider files have been created
this_env.Depends(sources, provider_sources)

sources_full = provider_sources + sources

# now we can compile the provider
this_env.SharedLibrary(libname, source=sources_full, staticlibs=staticlibs, dynamiclibs=dynamiclibs, installpath=install_dir)
```

I tried setting an explicit dependency so that the handwritten sources would not compile until all generated sources were created (this_env.Depends(sources, provider_sources)) but when running multi-threaded, SCons ignores this dependency and tries to compile the handwritten files before the autogeneration step has completed.

Comment: As long as your GenProvider() accurately lists its output files (targets) and any header files are generated into a path listed on CPPPATH then scons will not compile any source files which include those files until they are generated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the SideEffect() function as defined here:

[SCons Wiki: SideEffect](http://scons.org/wiki/SConsMethods/SideEffect)

Im not sure if it was created exactly for your need, but may help.

Comment: The autogeneration step does create a manifest file, so I attempted to use that as the SideEffect target:
 but unfortunately the problem persists, thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this by making the generated files targets of `Command`. For example, say you have a file `foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
int main() {}
```

And say that `foo.h` needs to be generated before `foo.c` can be built. You can do it like this:

```
import time

def build_foo(target, source, env):
    print("Generating foo source files")
    time.sleep(5)
    with open("foo.h", "w") as f:
        f.write("")
    # Generate bar.so, which we need later for X, blah blah blah
    print("Done generating")

env = Environment()
env.Command(['foo.h', 'bar.so'], 'foo.in', build_foo)
env.Program('foo', 'foo.c')
```

Build output looks like this:

```
$ scons -Q -j4
build_foo(["foo.h", "foo.so"], ["foo.in"])
Generating foo source files
Done generating
gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c
gcc -o foo foo.o
```

If you omit `foo.h` as a target (i.e. `env.Command(['bar.so'], 'foo.in', build_foo)`, the build output looks like this:

```
$ scons -Q -j4
gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c
build_foo(["foo.so"], ["foo.in"])
Generating foo source files
foo.c:2:10: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
 #include "foo.h"
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [foo.o] Error 1
Done generating
```

Comment: You added a sleep to your python action function?

Comment: @bdbaddog It's for illustrative purposes - to prove SCons will wait before building `foo` even if passing `-j4`. It's to simulate a generation step that takes a long time. Why the downvote?

Comment: Because you should not have to do anything special to make this work. If the builders/command specify all the targets and sources. And any applicable scanners are correct and provided with the right search paths CPPPATH for example, then it should just work..

Comment: @bdbaddog - what are you talking about? It's not obvious that you would need to list *headers files* as build targets - you don't need to do that with CMake. CMake you can just say your target depends on another target without explicitly listing any header files. Clearly this is not obvious to your average scons user. Hence, the existence of this question with 11 upvotes and 4 favorites.

Comment: i.e. it's not obvious why `Depends()` and `Requires()` and all the other scons APIs fail to prevent scons from building the two targets in parallel, but listing header files as a target succeeds in making scons serialize the dependency order.

Comment: Take a look at the output of "scons --tree=prune" with your Depends and Requires()  commented out. Likely you will see missing dependencies. This is likely due to not having some directory in your CPPPATH. So SCons can't find the header file to add to the implicit dependency list.   You should never have to add a Depends() from a object file to a header file (which is not generated).

Comment: Please come to SCons IRC (#scons on freenode.net) or Discord channel if you wish to discuss further. https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy or the SCons users mailing list. https://scons.org/lists.html